# Stored Procedure Pulling No Data

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

This code is to run and pull all the records that have a balance that is greater than $500, but when I run the code it display the column names and no data. I have tried multiple ways and get the same result.

```
Create Proc spBillingBlancedue
@hihgestBalancedue money
AS
begin
begin try
Select patients.PatientID, First_Name + ' ' + Last_Name AS Name,  Billing.Claims, Payment, Balance, (Claims + Payment + Balance) as TotalBill 
From Billing
Join Insurence_Billing
on Billing.BillingID = Insurence_Billing.BillingID
join Insurences 
on Insurence_Billing.InsurenceID = Insurences.InsurenceID
join Patients
on Patients.PatientID = Insurences.PatientID
Where Balance > @hihgestBalancedue
end try
begin catch
Print 'Error!'
end catch
end

--test
Declare @checkAmount money;
Set @checkAmount = 500.00;
EXEC spBillingBlancedue @checkAmount
```

Comment: Does the select return records without the where clause? If so, what is the data type of the Balance column?

Comment: try commenting out the `where`... if unsuccessful read about [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)s

Comment: You're also doing inner joins on all of the tables. Can you post sample data to support your query?

Comment: @JacobH I comment out the where clause and got the same thing

Comment: @giorgiga I comment out the where clause and got the same thing

Comment: There isn't much else we can do to help you without more information. We would need to see your table structures at least. If you comment out the where clause and have the same issue it is almost certainly a problem with the Join clauses.

Comment: Turn your joins into left outer joins and see what comes back with nulls.

Comment: @SQLCliff The Left outer joins worked! Thank you!

Comment: You're very welcome. Happy coding!